# How to add a text button inside ProfileListItem in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, expanded

How to add a TextButton here?

I Tried inside ProfileListItem creating a TextButton but can't

[image: 1]

Comment: what is expected  output ? also share your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to include your code, and show a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: please share your ProfileListItem